# React+Redux Hot module replacement crashing with '_pendingForceUpdate' undefined

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, hot-module-replacement, asp-net-core-spa-services

I have a react/redux with asp.net core as the back-end. Hot module replacement was working but unfortunately at some moment any change to a react component unloads the page and crashes in the console with:

```
[HMR] bundle rebuilding
client.js:207 [HMR] bundle rebuilt in 1141ms
client.js:199 [HMR] bundle rebuilding
client.js:207 [HMR] bundle rebuilt in 1976ms
process-update.js:27 [HMR] Checking for updates on the server...
vendor.js?v=Z8yGCzaP6rxOGgnos6PhMhr0V40qjsLRdHFCMY2G9u4:40 TypeError: Cannot 
read property '_pendingForceUpdate' of undefined
at setPendingForceUpdate (index.js:20)
at traverseRenderedChildren (index.js:6)
at deepForceUpdate (index.js:40)
at AppContainer.componentWillReceiveProps (AppContainer.dev.js:45)
at s (vendor.js?v=Z8yGCzaP6rxOGgnos6PhMhr0V40qjsLRdHFCMY2G9u4:40)
at updateClassInstance (vendor.js?v=Z8yGCzaP6rxOGgnos6PhMhr0V40qjsLRdHFCMY2G9u4:40)
at beginWork (vendor.js?v=Z8yGCzaP6rxOGgnos6PhMhr0V40qjsLRdHFCMY2G9u4:40)
at i (vendor.js?v=Z8yGCzaP6rxOGgnos6PhMhr0V40qjsLRdHFCMY2G9u4:40)
at a (vendor.js?v=Z8yGCzaP6rxOGgnos6PhMhr0V40qjsLRdHFCMY2G9u4:40)
at w (vendor.js?v=Z8yGCzaP6rxOGgnos6PhMhr0V40qjsLRdHFCMY2G9u4:40)
```

The project was created from the Visual Studio template for a ASP.NET Core+React+Redux app.

I noticed also, that it doesn't attach to server side rendering, earlier, if there was something wrong, VS made a break on the line causing the issue, no the .NET exception is just returned in plain text to the browser.

Honestly I don't even know were to start troubleshoot this set-up, any tips?

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reasons is that you are using production build of react. You can try to remove the dist folders (under wwwroot and ClientApp folder from template) and rebuild the project in debug configuration. Also, make sure that that you have NODE_ENV set to 'development' in your webpack configuration.

The issue may occur after you build the project in release configuration and then do not remove the dist folder under wwwroot. This is because of this default configuration in csproj file which triggers webpack build only when dist folder does not exist:

```
<Target Name="DebugRunWebpack" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('wwwroot\dist') ">
```